# How do I apply like a Global font-family in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, fonts, web, dreamweaver

I'm making a website for school coursework, it has over 200 pages as they have roughly 3 frames per page. My lecturer told me to completely rework the font as it's plain and boring, default text.

Is there a way for me to change the font for every single page with a code rather than having to go to each individual page to change it back.

Comment: We'd have to like see your code to advise you with this.

Comment: Ok. This is it. http://pastebin.com/fcwah4zx
That's a code for one of the index pages for a page which displays 3 pages. However the code I sent you is only the mainframe.

Comment: The issue is that you have your CSS in the head of your page rather than being in a separate CSS file. If you place your CSS in a separate file then link to that file in the HEAD of each of your pages then when you change the CSS it will update ALL PAGES at once.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file add

```
* {
  font-family: [your font];
}
```

Comment: It's still changing the font on only that page.

Comment: you need to have a single external css file linked to on every page to make changes globally. Once you have that, the above solution will fix every page. For example, in the `<head>` section of every page, you would add `<link href=" path to your css file relative to page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`, replacing the href with the path to the css file.

Comment: Yeah had a feeling you were going to say that. I guess I'm going to have to manually go through every page. Thanks anyways.

Comment: So you're looking for a solution to apply a font to every page & they don't have an external style sheet?